# Used yarn to add cors but there is an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I am facing this issue:

> error An unexpected error occurred: "/home/vagrant/.cache/yarn/v1/npm-cors-2.8.4-2bd381f2eb201020105cd50ea59da63090694686/.yarn-metadata.json: Unexpected end of JSON input".

A few things to note:

1. During the installation of cors (`yarn add cors`), my laptop died on battery.
2. The cors files are there in node modules but aren't listed in package.json.
3. I recently switched from npm to yarn and operate within vagrant VM.
4. Tried to delete files from node modules but id didn't make a difference

`yarn remove cors` gives this error:

> error This module isn't specified in a manifest.

Comment: remove the lock files as well as the node_modules folder, clear the cache, and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you've got broken yarn cache. Execute `yarn cache clean` and retry module installation.